# missing ".sty" package

Tags: latex, texlive

I have installed TexLive on Ubuntu 13.04 following the instructions provided in 
http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html

but I always get some missing .sty error (for instance siunitx.sty). I struggled a lot to make it run. double checked the PATH, etc. but could not figure out the problem.
do you know what the problem can be?

Best 
Mehdi

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `siunitx.sty` file appears to be part of package `texlive-science`

```
$ apt-cache show texlive-science | grep siunitx
  siunitx -- A comprehensive (SI) units package.
```

You should be able to install it from your package manager of choice, or via the command line using

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-science
```

Comment: `texlive-science` seems no longer to be available, and `siunitx.sty` is not in `texlive-latex-extra` despite the following message: "Package texlive-science is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  texlive-latex-extra"

Comment: @Reb.Cabin what is your Ubuntu version? There appears to still be [texlive-science in disco](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/texlive-science)

Comment: 18.04. I'm trying a `texlive-full` reinstall now.

Comment: This solution helped me find the missing `fourier.sty` file. Using the same technique as: `texlive-fonts | grep fourier`. As a result, `apt-cache` then found `texlive-fonts-extra` package and `grep` found `fourier.sty` within the output. Therefore, I installed the missing .sty via `apt-get install <package>`.

Comment: @steeldriver How would one figure this one if one doesn't already know that the answer is texlive-science?   E.g. I'm getting a similar error for a different font: `mathabx.sty` and it's not in texlive-science.

Comment: @DonHatch my go-to for this is the [apt-file](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/man1/apt-file.1.html) command - once installed and updated, you can do `apt-file search mathabx.sty` to find packages containing matching filenames